# Visual Studio Code terminal "sh: docker: command not found"

Tags: shell, visual-studio-code, terminal

I installed docker, but in vs code terminal it's don't work. Even if i try to swith shell to bash, when i execute echo $SHELL i got "/bin/sh". I installed vs code from flatpak and my os is Nobara.

I tried to switch shell in setting but got same result

Answer (score 0):

For macOS:

```
alias docker="/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources/bin/docker"
```